# Script in google sheet to clear, but not remove filter

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am completely new in writing scripts for google sheets, so I was hoping some of you could help/guide me a little bit.

So Ideally, I want a script to clear (not remove) ALL filters in my sheet. This is, however, complicated for me to do (If some of you have such a script, I would LOVE to see it :) )

Instead, I made this one (Used recorder):

```
function Clear_Filter() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(1);
  spreadsheet.getRange('B5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(2);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(3);
  spreadsheet.getRange('G5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(7);
  spreadsheet.getRange('J5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(10);
  spreadsheet.getRange('M5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(13);
};
```

So my filter is set in Row 5. First I made the above for all columns (I had 20), but the problem is, that the code is very slow :( So now I am using the columns, that I use the most, when filtering, but the code is still slow. Well the worst thing is, that the code is running one column at a time (which we see in the code), and when the code is finish, I end up in the last column.

Can I do something? I dont want my sheet window keep turning right, when I run the code, and then end up in column M.

I will appreciate any help!
Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can alter your recorded macro. If you don't want to move the active cell, I suggest removing calls that activate ranges. Google Apps Script (Sheets Macros) is JavaScript - feel free to apply programming techniques you would apply in normal JavaScript functions, such as declaring a variable for something you modify often, especially if you would have to repeat words and methods a lot - like `spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter()`, for instance. Additionally, there is a lot of reference documentation available - you can even get a direct link to it from the Script Editor Help menu!

Comment: this link might help https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/google-sheets-api/filters#TOC-Reset-all-existing-filters-on-a-given-range

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.
I just looked at the page, but I am not sure how to make it work.

So I tried the "Clear / remove all filters" code, but I am getting an error saying, that my sheet is not defined. In the code I replaced the "sheetId" with the name of my sheet.

Comment: A sheet id and a sheet name are not the same thing. Further, a sheet id and a spreadsheet id are also not the same thing. If your question is solved, and you feel the solution is worth writing an answer about (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), do so and accept it. If it's not worth an answer, consider deletion. If it not resolved (and you haven't fundamentally redefined the specific issue you are having, (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)), then make sure your question properly and usefully reflects your issue.

Answer (score 8):

Here is mine. The function does not remove filters. Instead, it clears them as requested.

```
function clearFilter(sheet) {
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); //for testing purpose only
  var filter = sheet.getFilter();
  if (filter !== null) {  // tests if there is a filter applied
    var range = filter.getRange(); // prevents exception in case the filter is not applied to all columns
    var firstColumn = range.getColumn();
    var lastColumn = range.getLastColumn();
    for (var i = firstColumn; i < lastColumn; i++) {
      filter.removeColumnFilterCriteria(i);
    }
  Logger.log('All filters cleared')
  }
  else {Logger.log('There is no filter')}
}
```

Comment: Confirmed this is the only way right now. If your code knows which columns are being filtered, you can also use setHiddenValues([]) to show all.
    `const criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues([]).build();
    filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(yourColNum, criteria);`

Comment: This is working for me as well. The only issue is it takes a lot of time if your spreadsheet is having large amount of data. any efficient solution maybe?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the answers (e.g. proposed by Birmin) work fine but the script is painfully slow. I find it much faster to reapply the filter:

```
function clearFilter(sheet) {
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); //for testing purpose only
  var filter = sheet.getFilter();
  if (filter !== null) {  // tests if there is a filter applied
    var range = filter.getRange();
    filter.remove();
    range.createFilter();
  Logger.log('All filters cleared')
  }
  else {Logger.log('There is no filter')}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset filters criterea + sort by first column (as default state).
And add this action to main menu.

```js
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [
    {name: "Reset filters", functionName: "ResetFilters"},
  ];
  ss.addMenu("Custom actions", menuEntries); // add to main menu
}

function ResetFilters() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var lastColumn = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getLastColumn();
  var filter = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().build(); 
  for (var i = 1; i <= lastColumn; i++) {
    filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(i, criteria);
  }
  filter.sort(1, true); // remove this line for disable setting of sorting order
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear all

```
`function turnOffFilter(sheet) {
        for (var index = 1; index < sheet.getLastColumn(); index++) {
          if (sheet.getFilter().getColumnFilterCriteria(index)) {
            sheet.getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(index);
          }
        }
    }`
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you will get an exception if the filter has not been applied to all the columns in the sheet. See the answer by @Birmin

Answer (score -2):

I, have you tried :

```
function Clear_Filter() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getFilter().remove();
}
```

Comment: This removes the entire filter, whereas the user has stated they do not want this to occur, they just want the filter criteria to be removed and the filters to remain in place.